# call javascript functions without receiver

Tags: javascript, function

Let's say we have a function:

```
function fn(){return this;}
```

If we call the function by `foo = fn();`, then `foo` will get the value of `this`, but I am curious about where the return goes if the the function is called without receiver, i.e. `fn();`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It goes nowhere. The returned values will not be referenced by anything and is "thrown away".

Answer (score 0):

Variables are used to allocate and keep memory in a persistent state.

When no variables are used, the memory that was used for processing and is released back to the pool.  The result of operations are not assigned any where.